# Azure devops test plans reports

Tags: azure, azure-devops

My team are using devops test plans to manage the testing effort.

We're currently using the built in reports that can be added to a test plan/suite but the problem we're finding with these is:

1, We cant get the level of access from the report that we'd like.
For instance if a member of the business from outside of the team wanted to be able to get a view of the overall status of the the test plan, i.e what suites have failing tests etc.
At present they need to open and navigate within the test plan itself in order to view a test report.
Is is possible to output or send the report by email or some other method so that stake holders don't need to go into the test plan to be able to view the data ?

2, The level of granularity:
we've been able to set up a few reports to detail the test progress at test suite level. For example, it is possible to see which test suites contain failing tests. (the problem is you are not able to see the names or ID's of the failing test cases unless you go into the test suite)

We'd like to be able to identify an individual failing test within a suite if possible .

Comment: Can you explain more about the problem 2? What is "pin point a failing test within a suite"?

Comment: pin point is another way of saying 'identify' Ive updated my post to avoid confusion

Comment: Hi Bobe, can you share more details about how you set up a few reports to detail the test progress at test suite level? By the way, there are some docs about Power BI integration with azure devops [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/sample-test-plans-aggregate-data-level?view=azure-devops&tabs=powerbi) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue 1:

You can use [the test results charts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/track-test-status?view=azure-devops#track-testing-progress) and then [share charts on your team's dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/track-test-status?view=azure-devops#share-charts-on-your-teams-dashboard). You must be a team administrator to configure the dashboard widget, but team members with Stakeholder access can view the charts on the dashboard. Then the Stakeholder users can see the test status on the dashboards.